# Choppy and Laggy audio in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, audio

My videos and audio files played fine in Premiere Pro yesterday, but today when I open the project file again, all the audio files, including those in videos, are choppy and laggy during playback. Tried opening new projects and with other audios and vids, the problem still exists. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience this can typically occur when Premiere is having either a hard time loading a buffer for the audio, or you're putting too much strain on your computer memory.

I'd clear out the Premiere cache, which you can do by going to “Preferences > Memory.”

If it's an issue that occurs through different clips, something tells me it's to do with either the amount of memory Premiere needs to process the realtime feedback for audio, or the bitrate of the clips. If your bitrate is too high, it'll DEFINITELY cause some playback issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try under Audio Hardware in Preferences, change Input to No Input. Why this had an impact on the audio in the timeline... I have no clue. But it fixed the issue when I had it.

Comment: This one helped me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this in case some poor soul comes here looking for the same issue and the above doesn't solve it:

I went into my Media Cache (C:\Users[YourName]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Common) and deleted all the files from "Media Cache", "Media Cache Files", and "Peak Files".

Tip: Do this with Premiere closed because sometimes files won't delete since Premiere is using them. (If you leave Premiere open, you'll have to restart it anyways since it will refer to the cache files to play audio, so you'll hear nothing)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution. It seems that if you have your file in a ONE DRIVE (cloud) folder, then it might bug.
I think it is because premiere pro needs to have directly access to the file, but when it's in a "OneDrive' or other cloud system service, the connection needed is way more than what it can provide to play it well.

It can be the same on Adobe Audition, I think that if it tries to "write" the file on a "OneDrive" folder it might bug.